# XLib: создать "maximized" окно

Tags: linux, x11, окно, xlib

Как в XLib создать окно c максимальным размером (не fullscreen)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Управляет состоянием окна не xlib, а оконный менеджер. Он может обработать определённые эвенты. [Собственно, ответ на старшем SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530786/xlib-create-window-in-mimized-or-maximized-state).

Код из ответа

```
XEvent xev;
Atom wm_state  =  XInternAtom(dpy, "_NET_WM_STATE", False);
Atom max_horz  =  XInternAtom(dpy, "_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_HORZ", False);
Atom max_vert  =  XInternAtom(dpy, "_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_VERT", False);

memset(&xev, 0, sizeof(xev));
xev.type = ClientMessage;
xev.xclient.window = win;
xev.xclient.message_type = wm_state;
xev.xclient.format = 32;
xev.xclient.data.l[0] = _NET_WM_STATE_ADD;
xev.xclient.data.l[1] = max_horz;
xev.xclient.data.l[2] = max_vert;

XSendEvent(dpy, DefaultRootWindow(dpy), False, SubstructureNotifyMask, &xev);
```